# A property of the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

How can one prove, that $0$ is the only value of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ taken infinitely often?

What I tried:

To see how the graph looks like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin+x%29%2Fx

The function is continuous and has infinitely many positive and negative values, so by Darboux it has infinitely many zeroes.

Also, the line $y=0$ is an asymptote both in $\pm\infty$, but this thing only, doesn't imply the result. What else should I use?

Comment: $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: I wrote I know this

Comment: That is enough to prove your statement.

Comment: Really? What about $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(+2,+\infty)$, $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(-1,1)$ and something on $[-2,2]\setminus[-1,1]$ ? This one also satisfies $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, but the value $1$ is also taken infinitely many times?

Comment: The function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\frac 1x)}{x}$$ has the same H.A. but takes every value an infinite number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0\ne r\in [-1,1].$ Let $f_r(x)=-rx+\sin x.$

Since $\frac {\sin x}{x}\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty,$ take $M>0 $ such that $|x|>M\implies \left|\frac {\sin x}{x}\right|<|r|\implies f_r(x)\ne 0.$

Now $f_r'(x)=-r+\cos x$ so the set $S=\{x\in [-M,M]: f'_r(x)=0\}$ is finite. So let $S\cup \{-M,M\}=\{x_j: 1\le j\le n\}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N,$ where $x_j<x_{j+1}$ for each $j<n.$

Now $f_r$ is strictly monotonic on each interval $[x_j,x_{j+1}]$ for $j<n$ because $f'_r$ is continuous and non-$0$ on $(x_j,x_{j+1}).$ So there is at most one $x\in [x_j,x_{j+1}]$ such that $f_r(x)=0.$

We could also say there is a member of $(f'_r)^{-1}\{0\}$ between any 2 members of $f_r^{-1}\{0\}$ so if $[-M,M]\cap f_r^{-1}\{0\}$ was infinite then $[-M,M]\cap (f_r')^{-1}\{0\}$ would be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an even function, this is equivalent to other values being achieved by only finitely many $x>0$. As @AnginaSend and @JCAA noted, you just need the limit at $\infty$. Since $-\frac1x\le\frac{\sin x}{x}\le\frac1x$, by the squeeze theorem $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$. This means$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N>0\forall x>N\left(\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|<\epsilon\right).$$In particular,$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N>0\forall x>0\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}-\epsilon=0\implies x\in(0,\,N]\right).$$Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ only has finitely many turning points on any set of the form $(0,\,N]$ (proof is an exercise), with no intervals of positive width on which it's constant, we're done.

Comment: Is there an easy way to show the function can take a value only finitely many times in a bounded interval though? It is trivial if we can use the identity theorem from complex analysis, but not sure OP is allowed to use it.

Comment: The derivative is zero only finitely many times in any closed interval which implies that we can split any closed interval in finitely many pieces (number depending on interval of course) where $f$ is strictly monotonic, hence injective; it is not that hard to do it quantitatively and get precise numbers of zeroes for the derivative either

Comment: @Mark Note also the turning points of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ occur at fixed points of $\tan x$. You can easily show those occur at most once in an interval of the form  $((n-1/2)\pi,\,(n+1/2)\pi)$.